# Postgresql shell query wrapping

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am using Postgresql's shell client, psql. If I type a query that extends past the console width, the shell does horizontal "scrolling", i.e. I have to move the cursor around to see the full contents of the query. The screenshot below shows an example.

Is it possible to change this to wrap the query instead? There are many use cases where I like to copy the query. If not, are there any alternative console-based clients that are potential alternatives?

[image]

Comment: That behaviour is part of your terminal client / readline library. `psql` doesn't have much control over it.

Comment: One thing you can control is wrapping of query output via `\pset format wrapped`, but agreed that that wouldn't affect scrolling on things like typing out a query.